# Command "generate-types" is not defined

Tags: symfony, yaml, schema, api-platform.com

I'm trying to generate types from the schema.yaml file, which I created

schema.yaml

```
types:
  product:
    properties:
      name: {nullable: false}
      description: {nullable: false}
      image: { range: "Text"}

  Offer:
    properties:
      url: {nullable: false}
      price: {nullable: false, range: "Number"}
      priceCurrency: {nullable: false}
```

Then when I execute the following command

```
vendor/bin/schema generate-types src/ config/schema.yaml
```

I will receive the following error:

***Command "generate-types" is not defined***

I tried to know what is the reason but I couldn't find it out.
Where can I defined the command: generate-types

My smfony version is 5.3

thanks a lot

Comment: Please be more precise about how to reproduce your error in the future. For example, you refer to a `vendor/bin/schema` without stating how it came to be. We dislike googling unexplained magic to understand what you're doing; in this case you should have mentioned that you use API Platform which provides this tool.

Comment: thx for the tip

Answer (score 0):

See [this changelog](https://github.com/api-platform/schema-generator/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> The `generate-types` command has been renamed `generate`

You need to change `generate-types` to `generate`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, now I have another error.

it's like this: ***String could not be parsed as XML***

Comment: first warning:

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /var/www/api/vendor/api-platform/schema-generator/src/Command/GenerateCommand.php on line 157

Comment: second warning:

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/api/vendor/api-platform/schema-generator/src/Command/GenerateCommand.php on line 157

Comment: third warning:
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(https://purl.org/goodrelations/v1.owl): Failed to open stream: operation failed in /var/www/api/vendor/api-platform/schema-generator/src/Command/GenerateCommand.php on line 157

Comment: fourth warning:

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://purl.org/goodrelations/v1.owl" in /var/www/api/vendor/api-platform/schema-generator/src/Command/GenerateCommand.php on line 157

Comment: That looks like a general setup problem which I'm afraid I cannot help you with. You may want to ask a new question which details your setup to get help with this.